# Opening DB connection in class method

Tags: php

To open a DB connection, I currently use this class method :

```
    function openDB() {


// 1. Create a database connection
$conn = mysqli_connect("x" , "x", "x","x");
if (!$conn)
{
    $this->error_msg = "connection error could not connect to the database:! ";  
    return false;
}
$this->conn = $conn;
return true;
}
```

However, I want to instead use my config file

```
require("assets/configs/db_config.php");
```

Obviously this file contains the DB connection information.

How can I do away with

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("x" , "x", "x","x");
```

And simply make $conn and make it use DB_Config.php instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For you config file return an array of the values you need

```
 return array("host"=>"example.com", "dbname"=>"mydb", "username"=>"dbuser", "password"=>"secret");
```

Then in your openDb function do this.

```
function openDB() {
  // 1. Create a database connection
  $config = include("/path/to/config.php");
  $conn = mysqli_connect($config["host"] , $config["username"], $config["password"],$config["dbname"]);
  if (!$conn)
  {
    $this->error_msg = "connection error could not connect to the database:! ";  
    return false;
  }
  $this->conn = $conn;
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
function openDB()
```

to

```
function openDB($server, $user, $pass, $dbName)
```

and pass those variables to mysqli_connect

and pass data from included file.I suppose, you have them in some sort of constants or defines.

Also, it would be good idea to haveDB connection somewhere globally.

Comment: Yes, I do : `<?php 

$server = 'x';
$user = 'x';
$pass = 'x';
$db = 'x';
$mysqli = new mysqli($server , $user  , $pass ,$db);


mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR);


?>` So what would I do within the function. $conn needs to be defined with the connection still?